# Can a pixel be divided into smaller pixels? Or is it possible to have 1.54 pixels instead of 1 or 2?

Tags: c, floating-point, resize, pixel, bmp

I am doing an exercise where I have to resize an image "f" times. "f" is a float, so I have to consider 1.45, 3.54, and so on. I don't want you to solve the problem, but I have some doubts about it.

A pixel is 24bits in a BMP file, right? Because it is RGB, so it has 1 byte for red, 1 byte for green and 1 byte for blue. So how am I supposed to divide a pixel? If I have 2.67 for example, then 0.67 how would that work? Dividing a pixel means dividing an 3 bytes, but there is a limit how I can divide them, also, RGB would dissapear, because if I divided by half, then I would only have 12bits, not enough to store RGB.

Also when I am copying pixel by pixel, is it possible to copy instead of pixel by pixel, to copy 0.01 pixel each time? meaning that if it takes me 1 step to copy 1 pixel (1 pixel at a time), then if I copy 0.01 pixel each time, means it would take me 100 times the time it took me to copy a whole pixel. It sounds completely weird for me, because copying 0.01 pixel at a time means copying 0.01 byte at a time, and that may screw the image up if I am resizing (I think).

I have tried with integers, but for example, a for loop will not work in the floating point, because of all the possibilities.

Comment: Rescaling of images is done by calculating new values for pixels. For example, suppose you are scaling a line (instead of a two-dimensional image) by 2, and the pixel at 4 is 100% red while the pixel at 5 is 100% green. The new image would of course have a 100% red pixel at 8 and a 100% green pixel at 10, but what goes at 9? You could put a pixel that is 50% red and 50% green there. But then there are complications. If you are scaling by 1.5, the red pixel at 4 goes to a red pixel at 6, but the green pixel at 5 goes to 7.5. So the pixels at 7 and 8 have to be set to something that comes…

Comment: … partly from this 100% green pixel. But, if you calculate some average with nearby pixels, no resulting pixel will be 100% green. Some of the brightness of the original image will be lost. Another complication is that two-dimensional images result in targets inside squares defined by four pixels, so interpolation has to be done in two dimensions. There are a variety of methods to choose, and there is no one right answer. If you are doing an exercise, there should be more guidance on what is expected for this exercise.

Comment: In theory a pixel cannot be broken up. However, there are techniques such as sub-pixel rendering that take advantage of low-level knowledge of the user's display layout to light up red/green/blue elements independently in order to get finer control over the outline of text than is theoretically possible.

Comment: Oh, and just so we're clear, I don't believe anyone is asking you to use only some of the RGB bits and discard the others. I'm almost certain that that cannot be the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're being asked to split an individual pixel.  It sounds like you're being asked to add or remove pixels when an image is resized.  For example, suppose you have an image that is 12 x 12 pixels and you are given a factor of 1.3 to expand by.  This gives you a new image size of 15.6 x 15.6, which rounds to 16 x 16.

Then you need to perform a mapping of pixels in the original image to pixels in the resized image.  A simple way to do this is to take the x and y coordinates of the larger image and multiply them (or divide them) by the scaling factor to get the corresponding coordinates in the smaller image, then copy the whole pixel from the old to the new image.  Given the above example, pixel (13,14) in the larger image corresponds to x = 13/1.3 = 10 and y = 14 / 1.3 = ~10.76 (rounds to 11), so copy pixel (10,11) in the old image to (13,14) in the new image.

Comment: But what if the scaling factor is 0.5. If I round it then it would be 1. So no scaling has been done, but the user would be asking for it to be half the size.

Comment: @Max You don't round the scaling factor.  You round the *result* of multiplying or dividing by the scaling factor.

Answer (score 1):

@dbush was very clear. But you can also make a deeper scale algorithm with these two observations.

#### Observation 1

In @dbush example, he tries to expand a 12 x 12 to a 16 x 16 because 15.6 x 15.6 is impossible to make (since pixels are a discrete unit). But by doing this the scale factor is no longer 1.3, it is 16/12 = 1.333333333333333 now. So you can use that number to make the adjustments he says.

#### Observation 2

In @dbush example, the pixel (13, 14) (counting pixels from 0 to 15 I suppose) is mapped to the pixel (10, 10.76). Since this pixel doesn't exist, he rounds its coordinates to use (10, 11) instead. But (10, 10.76) represents the coordinate of the upper left corner of a little rectangle inside the original image. A normal pixel is a square of size 1 x 1. But this little rectangle has the size of a pixel scaled by the same factor of 1.3. The size of this little rectangle is 1/1.3 = 0.78 (aprox.). Which means that this little rectangle has its lower right corner at (10.78, 11.54).

This little rectangle which has to be mapped to the new image has 11 - 10.76 = 0.24 units of its height inside pixel (10, 10), and 11.54 - 11 = 0.54 units of its height inside pixel (10, 11). So the RGB values for the new pixel must be a weighted sum of the RGB values of pixels (10, 10) and (10, 11) using 0.24 and 0.54 as weights respectively. This will grant your code the power to scale images by factors smaller than 1.

#### Notes

- I used the word "rectangle" because I was considering the fact that an image could have a horizontal scale factor different than the vertical scale factor. In this particular case, the scale was 1.3 for both horizontal and vertical.
- The weighted sum uses only height as weights because the little rectangle only intersects 2 pixels in the vertical axis. It happened that in the horizontal axis the little rectangle was inside a single pixel. But there could be a scenario where the rectangle will be intersecting pixel both horizontally and vertically, or even intersecting more than 2 pixels in the same axis. So the weighted sum should be prepared to consider more than 2 pixels in the same axis and to use areas instead of widths or heights if both axes are considered for a single rectangle.

Comment: how do you know that the lower right corner is at (10.78, 11.54)? I don't really understand what you mean after that.

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer. Hope this new explanation will help.

Answer (score 0):

Pixel represents the point on the screen and it is atomic. I'd you need to resize the screen you need to create an algorithm which will increase or decrease the number of rows and columns so hot having pixel parts.